# UserControl Click Event

Tags: c#, wpf, onclick

I have created some User Controls to be used like buttons. The problem, is that `UserControl` doesn't have the `Click` event, only the `MouseLeftClickDown` and `MouseLeftClickUp`.
Both events are great for triggers and visual animations, but I really need the `Click` event.

For example, I have a user control for closing the window. If i use the `MouseLeftClickUp` event to close the window, the window will close when the user does a `mouseleftclickdown` in any part of the window, and releases in the usercontrol. This is not safe.
I know this question has been asked a few times, but I haven't found any good answer yet. Is there any simple way to achieve this? I´m really trying to avoid Custom controls, as I don't fully understand them. I´m just starting with WPF.

Comment: I am not sure if i understand your situation correctly. Why are you not using a simple button for that purpose?

Comment: :) ... learning is the way, young padawi ... not much to do but learn. Read and play with things ... this is how you learn ...

Comment: Because in my usercontrol I have several shapes, triggers and animations. I´m confortable with that because I can use expression blend.

Comment: @Andres, look at **ControlTemplate**. You can give a button (almost) any appearance you want, even with those shapes triggers and animations of yours. Heck, if you want, although it doesn't really make sense, you can turn the button's appearance into that of half a dozen listboxes arranged side-by-side plus some funky TreeView - doesn't make sense, but is technically possible. That is one of the powers of WPF... (although admittedly, tweaking ControlTemplates is perhaps not as sexy as Expression Blend ;) )

Comment: If i use a usercontrol i have one xaml file where i can edit it with blend. Is there any way where i can do the same with a button with a custom template?

Comment: Im sorry with this question. I was trying to achieve something that can be easily done in another way. I found this microsoft tutorial to create a button from shapes in expression blend. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613598(v=vs.110).aspx. Special thanks for @elgonzo that put me in the right track. Hope this question can help a newbie in wpf like me :)

Answer (score -1):

You can create your own routed event, or I think you can use `Button.Click` in your UserControl XAML as an attribute. Don't quote me on that, I've seen it somewhere.

See this thread

[How can I create a click event on a custom user control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929148/how-can-i-create-a-click-event-on-a-custom-user-control/19929643#19929643)